# Orbeon 4.3 username column exception when searching forms

Tags: mysql, orbeon

When trying to view a form's summary page or searching a form I get an search error and in the logs it reports `An Error has Occurred: Column 'username' not found.`

Each of the 4 tables Orbeon_Form_Data, Orbeon_Form_Definition, Orbeon_Form_Data_Attach, and Orbeon_Form_Definition_Attach ***all have username columns which are empty***. I added a value to these fields to see if that matters (thinking maybe a null issue) but I get the same error.

The form data and definition seem to be saving properly. I'm not sure where Orbeon is looking for the username column.

Here's an excerpt from the server.log

```
09:56:11,984 WARN  [org.exist.http.Descriptor] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Giving up unable to read descriptor file from C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp\vfs\tempd072dcd37da36635\orbeon.war-8bd76bd2d270189a\WEB-INF\descriptor.xml
09:56:11,984 WARN  [org.exist.http.Descriptor] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Giving up unable to read descriptor.xml file from classloader in package org.exist.http
09:56:12,875 INFO  [org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-16) /fr/service/exist/form/test/test - Timing: 3782
09:56:12,890 INFO  [org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-15) /fr/service/persistence/form/test/test - Timing: 4187
09:56:12,921 INFO  [org.orbeon.oxf.processor.transformer.xslt.XSLTTransformer] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-14) *
09:56:12,968 ERROR [org.orbeon.oxf.controller.PageFlowControllerProcessor] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-14) error caught {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "POST", path: "/fr/service/mysql/search/test/test"}
09:56:13,078 ERROR [org.orbeon.oxf.controller.PageFlowControllerProcessor] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-14) 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Column 'username' not found.                                                                                          |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml                                                        |reading page view data output |  59|
|······················································································································|
|element=<service path="/fr/service/mysql/search/([^/^.]+)/([^/^.]+)" view="persistence/mysql/search.xpl"/>            |
|view   =persistence/mysql/search.xpl                                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/apps/fr/persistence/mysql/search.xpl                                         |reading processor output      | 390|
|······················································································································|
|element=<p:output name="data" ref="data"/>                                                                            |
|name   =data                                                                                                          |
|ref    =data                                                                                                          |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/apps/fr/persistence/mysql/search.xpl                                         |executing XSLT transformation |    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: java.sql.SQLException                                                                                      |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError                            |createSQLException            |SQLError.java                 |1078|
|com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError                            |createSQLException            |SQLError.java                 | 989|
|com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError                            |createSQLException            |SQLError.java                 | 975|
|com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError                            |createSQLException            |SQLError.java                 | 920|
|com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl                       |findColumn                    |ResultSetImpl.java            |1167|
|org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet       |findColumn                    |WrappedResultSet.java         | 299|
|on.oxf.processor.sql.interpreters.GetterInterpreter|start                         |GetterInterpreter.java        |  96|
|rocessor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler|startElement                  |SQLProcessor.java             | 503|
|f.processor.sql.interpreters.RowIteratorInterpreter|startElement                  |RowIteratorInterpreter.java   | 166|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xml.SAXStore                        |replay                        |SAXStore.java                 | 310|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xml.SAXStore                        |replay                        |SAXStore.java                 | 236|
|rocessor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler|repeatBody                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 549|
|f.processor.sql.interpreters.RowIteratorInterpreter|start                         |RowIteratorInterpreter.java   |  95|
|rocessor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 529|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xml.SAXStore                        |replay                        |SAXStore.java                 | 322|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xml.SAXStore                        |replay                        |SAXStore.java                 | 236|
|rocessor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler|repeatBody                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 549|
|oxf.processor.sql.interpreters.ResultSetInterpreter|start                         |ResultSetInterpreter.java     |  75|
|rocessor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 529|
|processor.sql.SQLProcessor$ForwardingContentHandler|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 635|
|rocessor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 542|
|processor.sql.SQLProcessor$ForwardingContentHandler|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 635|
|rocessor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 542|
|processor.sql.SQLProcessor$ForwardingContentHandler|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 635|
|rocessor.sql.SQLProcessor$InterpreterContentHandler|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 542|
|beon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessor$RootInterpreter|endElement                    |SQLProcessor.java             | 290|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xml.SAXStore                        |replay                        |SAXStore.java                 | 322|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xml.SAXStore                        |replay                        |SAXStore.java                 | 236|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessor          |execute                       |SQLProcessor.java             | 251|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.sql.SQLProcessor$1        |readImpl                      |SQLProcessor.java             |  89|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 258|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 404|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 266|
|on.oxf.processor.transformer.xslt.XSLTTransformer$1|runTransformer                |XSLTTransformer.java          | 467|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|org.orbeon.oxf.common.OrbeonLocationException$     |wrapException                 |OrbeonLocationException.scala |  60|
|org.orbeon.oxf.common.OrbeonLocationException      |wrapException                 |OrbeonLocationException.scala |    |
|on.oxf.processor.transformer.xslt.XSLTTransformer$1|runTransformer                |XSLTTransformer.java          | 526|
|on.oxf.processor.transformer.xslt.XSLTTransformer$1|readImpl                      |XSLTTransformer.java          | 188|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 258|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 404|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1$1|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        |  93|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|executeChildren               |PipelineProcessor.java        | 680|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor|access$000                    |PipelineProcessor.java        |  60|
|g.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1|readImpl                      |PipelineProcessor.java        |  91|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 258|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 404|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 266|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.IdentityProcessor$1       |readImpl                      |IdentityProcessor.java        |  34|
|essor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter|read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 258|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl  |read                          |ProcessorOutputImpl.java      | 404|
|org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl             |readInputAsSAX                |ProcessorImpl.java            | 262|
|orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineProcessor$1$1|run                           |PipelineProcessor.java        |  93|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
|org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService             |service                       |ProcessorService.scala        |  41|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  74|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$                    |withRootException             |ScalaUtils.scala              | 120|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet               |service                       |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet                     |service                       |HttpServlet.java              | 847|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 329|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 248|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve      |invoke                        |StandardWrapperValve.java     | 275|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve      |invoke                        |StandardContextValve.java     | 161|
|oss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve|invoke                        |SecurityContextAssociationValv| 153|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke                        |StandardHostValve.java        | 155|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve        |invoke                        |ErrorReportValve.java         | 102|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve       |invoke                        |StandardEngineValve.java      | 109|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service                       |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 368|
|org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor           |process                       |Http11Processor.java          | 877|
|oyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler|process                       |Http11Protocol.java           | 671|
|org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker      |run                           |JIoEndpoint.java              | 930|
|java.lang.Thread                                   |run                           |                              |    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ {}
09:56:13,171 INFO  [org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-14) /fr/service/mysql/search/test/test - Timing: 4953
09:56:13,171 INFO  [org.orbeon.oxf.processor.DatabaseContext] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-14) Committing JDBC connection for datasource: jdbc/mysql.
09:56:13,187 INFO  [org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-6) /fr/service/persistence/search/test/test - Timing: 5094
09:56:13,218 ERROR [org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.processor.XFormsServer] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-2) xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|xf:submission for submission id: search-submission, error code received when submitting instance: 500                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsSubmissionException                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|getReplacer                   |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 730|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        | 101|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  71|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission    |submitCallable                |BaseSubmission.java           | 100|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission |connect                       |RegularSubmission.java        | 124|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|doSubmit                      |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 464|
|.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|performDefaultAction          |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 296|
|ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                | 125|
|ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  74|
|ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  74|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.Logging$class                  |withDebug                     |Logging.scala                 |  43|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withDebug                     |Dispatch.scala                |  23|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                |  74|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  73|
|.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  73|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withEvent$1                   |Dispatch.scala                |  38|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |dispatchEvent                 |Dispatch.scala                |  72|
|g.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.actions.XFormsSendAction|execute                       |XFormsSendAction.scala        |  51|
|org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAction          |execute                       |XFormsAction.scala            |  36|
|rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsActionInterpreter|runSingleIteration            |XFormsActionInterpreter.java  | 205|
|---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
|org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.ProcessorService             |service                       |ProcessorService.scala        |  41|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  74|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$                    |withRootException             |ScalaUtils.scala              | 120|
|org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet               |service                       |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  67|
|javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet                     |service                       |HttpServlet.java              | 847|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 329|
|org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 248|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve      |invoke                        |StandardWrapperValve.java     | 275|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve      |invoke                        |StandardContextValve.java     | 161|
|oss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve|invoke                        |SecurityContextAssociationValv| 153|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke                        |StandardHostValve.java        | 155|
|org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve        |invoke                        |ErrorReportValve.java         | 102|
|org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve       |invoke                        |StandardEngineValve.java      | 109|
|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service                       |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 368|
|org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor           |process                       |Http11Processor.java          | 877|
|oyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler|process                       |Http11Protocol.java           | 671|
|org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker      |run                           |JIoEndpoint.java              | 930|
|java.lang.Thread                                   |run                           |                              |    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"}
```

I've searched the documentation for "username" and I can only find reference to a username in the HTTP header.

Edit:
Here is a sample row from the orbeon_form_definition table. You can see that there is no username stored, but the column is there (XML value removed for readability).

```
created, last_modified, username, app, form, deleted, xml
2013-09-11 09:24:30, 2013-09-11 09:24:30, , test, test, N, <xh:html ......>
```

Comment: I downgraded to 4.2 and re-used my current configs and it worked right away. Not sure if there's a problem with 4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experimented same issue (username column exists in the mysql's table). Searching for a while I have found that this question also has been posted in the official forum.

As you have suggested [here](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Column-username-not-found-error-when-searching-or-showing-form-summary-td4657308.html) downgrading to version 4.2 will solve the issue. Seems to be a bug on version 4.3. I post here the link to help anybody with same issue.

A workaround, if you want to still use version 4.3, is to avoid summary page. For accessing a form, you can use the URL:

```
`http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/<<document_id>>`
```

Where 'document_id' is the identificator of the form on the MySQL table. This workaround do not let you to save again the form, unless you remove the old form in the mysql_table or you will have a "duplicate primary key error". This will only happen if you have a primary key defined into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Now I can assure that MySQL is working better in Orbeon 4.4 and this error is solve in this version. You need to use the update script for mysql database: [mysql-4_3-to-r_4](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/fr/persistence/relational/ddl/mysql-4_3-to-4_4.sql). Some new fields are added in version 4.4 and others have change their names.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of the documentation is [here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers). You will see that the tables do have a `username` column.

Comment: All my tables *do* have username columns